# Having another dropdown on a dropdown

Tags: html, dropdown

I have this dropdown on my navbar which looks like this:

[image: Navbar Dropdown]

Now I added a "Contact Us" tab on "HR & Admin" menu.

[image: ContactUs]

So is it possible to make "Contact Us" a dropdown **based on my code**?

Here's my html:

```html
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-navbar-collapse">
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav main-navbar-nav">
                        <li class="active"><a href="index.php" title="">HOME</a></li>
                        <li class="dropdown">
                            <a href="#" title="" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">HR & Admin <span class="caret"></span></a>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                <li><a href="coc.php" title="">C.O.C.</a></li>
        <li><a href="coc.php" title="">Contact Us</a></li>
                                <li><a href="job.php" title="">Job Vacancies</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
```

Comment: Yes, it's possible. What have you tried so far?

Comment: @JonUleis I haven't tried anything yet, I'm sorry. I just wanted to know if that's possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes like so, leave the css to you of course:-

```html
<ul class="nav navbar-nav main-navbar-nav">
    <li class="active"><a href="index.php" title="">HOME</a></li>
    <li class="dropdown">
        <a href="#" title="" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true"
           aria-expanded="false">HR & Admin <span class="caret"></span></a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="coc.php" title="">C.O.C.</a></li>
            <li><a href="coc.php" title="">Contact Us</a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu-2">
                    <li><a href="#" title="">Link</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" title="">Link</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" title="">Link</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="job.php" title="">Job Vacancies</a></li>
            
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just add another ul li inside your Contact Us li like so:

```
<li><a href="coc.php" title="">Contact Us</a></li>
    <ul>
        <li>Example 1</li>
        <li>Example 2</li>
    </ul>
</li>
```